# Getting length of text selection AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

How could I get the length number of a input text selected?

Like, if the text has 2 characters selected, then, it would return me length 2.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use textfield.selectionBeginIndex and textfield.selectionEndIndex to count chars currently selected.

```
var selected:int = field.selectionEndIndex - field.selectionBeginIndex;
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#selectionBeginIndex